# choice datatype default value is select

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have choice field and default value is "select" even though the field is set to have a value . the users can select can submit the form with "select".

is there any way we can validate the form while submitting ?. I am not using infopath. The default form of sharepoint in sharepoint online.

Comment: Mark the choice field as required and see if this changes anything.

Comment: it is marked as required. but when you submit "select"  will get inserted as select is the default value.

Comment: weird, did you add "select" in the choices?

Comment: yes i did, and set it as default. otherwise first item will be there by default and when the user submits without paying attention that will get added.

Comment: Oh than it's not SharePoint fault, if you add "select" as a valid choice value, user can choose "select" and submit the form. The only way is to make it required and remove select. In that case user has to pay attention to what he is submitting :)

Comment: cant we enforce a rule like it is in infopath ?